# C# AAD Authentication Fallback Options

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

This is not a question for a problem in code, but more of an architectural question.

We're implementing AAD Auth on a couple webapps and the topic came up of "What if AAD is unavailable? Can we add a back door or implement a technique to get into the system via a password auth branch or something?"

The search results of trying to answer that question:

- How to setup C# aad auth
- How to setup Azure AD Sync
- Hybrid AAD

I personally don't feel even remotely confident of enabling a "backdoor" password option. Security holes seem inevitable.

Running a second parallel master branch seems possible, but is annoying to say the least.

Has anyone else had to approach this question? What did you do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thread is one way to do it: [Combine Azure-AD with local user database in dotnet core 2 web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387682/combine-azure-ad-with-local-user-database-in-dotnet-core-2-web-api)

Essentially you would create another authprovider, in this case a local user db, then determine which auth provider based on some logic.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think we're going to apply this but I will mark bring it up.